# Visual Studio builds new Assembly Version after changing Publish Profile, Multiple IIS server published

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, web-publishing

I'm publishing my application to two separate IIS servers. The problem I have is when publishing to profile01 it builds the project and then publishes successfully. I then Publish again but switch to profile02. Upon doing this it builds the solution again (changing assembly version #) and publishes to the other server.

Now I have mismatched versions between server 01 and server02.

I'm assuming that when I change Profiles it makes a change somewhere to the project, once that change is made VS assumes a new build is required.

Any thoughts, suggestions, references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Web Deployment package & deploy this package to multiple servers. Documentation on how to create and deploy using the package is available here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx